# Google knows my language when I use Tor

Tags: security, google, private

When I go to google.com (without being logged in) it switches to google.de (I am from Germany), even though I am using Tor. How is this information still available to google?

Tor Browser Bundle 5.0.2. on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: This describes a problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: I just observed the same issue while the tor browser displayed IP addresses from Switzerland and France. However, after renewing the tor circuit again it again it worked as expected with addresses from other countries.

Comment: @JensKubieziel: Aren't 'off-topic' and 'unlikely to help future readers' two completely different things? What would have been the right place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably coincidence. Germany has a lot of exit nodes. (Are you using the Tor Browser Bundle?)

Comment: Yes, but the exit note was in France.

Comment: How did you determine that? Not all your circuits / connections use the same exit. Also, we don't know how Google maps IP addresses to languages.

Comment: Because Tor Browser said so.

Comment: I don't know what that means. As far as I know, my Tor Browser does not indicate where it exits. If you mean something like check.torproject.org, then again, not all your connections use the same exit. It's even possible that your initial connection and the redirected connection use different exits.

Comment: What I mean is this:

http://imgur.com/1MU9qwS

(Switzerland in this case, it was France before). Apologies for the quality, it wouldn't let me take a screenshot from the menu.

Comment: Hm, I just tried opening google.com in a few different tabs (meaning different connections), and it always stayed english. Maybe - as you said - it's related to how Google maps IP adresses ...

Comment: Thanks for the photo. I don't have that in my TBB (5.0.2 on OSX)

Comment: Interesting, running the same version on Ubuntu 15.04 ...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably in your HTTP_ACCEPT headers. See
https://panopticlick.eff.org/

If you can see your language there, so can other sites you visit. Mine says:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT: Headers  text/html, */* gzip, deflate en-US,en;q=0.5
```

Comment: Nope, it always says the same (en-US) no matter where the exit point is.

I think the answer is that Googles IP adress mapping went wrong. With other exit nodes, Google mostly appears in the respective language.

Thanks anyway!